# NFS4, insecure, port number, rdma contradiction help

Tags: nfs, port, nfsv4, rdma

- With RHEL 8.8 currently, and RHEL 9.x, the latest NFS version is 4.2.
- When NFS 4 was introduced, it did away with a few things in NFS3 one of which was multiple port numbers:

  - *NFS4 **mandates** all traffic now exclusively TCP **uses the single well known port 2049**.*
  - https://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/SNIA_An_Overview_of_NFSv4-3_0.pdf
  - you can find more mostly reputable articles stating the same thing.
  - I have confirmed this by having only TCP 2049 open in firewalld for NFS 4.1 in RHEL 7.9; it does not use port 111 or any other unless you change the default configurations of `/etc/nfs.conf` or `/etc/sysconfig/nfs`.  And in fact when I did get rdma working (over port 20049) that the rdma protocol specifically bypasses firewalld, an inherent aspect of why rdma saves cpy cycles and is faster i suppose.

> The NFS **insecure** option in `/etc/exports`  sets the server to listen to a request from any port on the client. Changing it to 'secure' (default) makes sure that the server will listen to only requests originating from ports 1-1024 of the client. Thus an unauthorized user on the client is kept from starting an NFS dialogue.  For reference : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246527/what-is-insecure-about-the-insecure-option-of-nfs-exports

The default is **secure** vs *insecure* when doing an NFS4 export if neither is mentioned in `/etc/exports`.

With **security rules** it is oftentimes stated  *The NFS server must not have the insecure file locking option enabled.*.

First with the `/etc/exports` `secure` option in play, be default, the *will only operate on secure ports less than 1024` seems to be completely not true since NFS4 runs on port 2049.  The number 2049 is greater than 1024... what am I missing?

With regards to `RDMA` which by convention happens on port `20049` there seems to be a little missed fact that one needs to **explicitly** state the **insecure** option in `/etc/exports` if a `mount -o rdma` is to be used otherwise the mount always happens as `proto=tcp` and not `proto=rdma` with no indication why.

I did validate that, using `MLNX_OFED_LINUX-23.04-1.1.3.0-rhel8.8-x86_64.iso` installed in place of the Redhat `InfiniBand Support` packages that a `mount -o rdma,port=1023` does work with a `mount` on the client side showing `proto=rdma`.

**However** one must also do (with MLNX only?) an `echo rdma 20049 > /proc/sys/nfsd/portlist`.  Or in the case with secure export an *echo rdma 1023*.  Does anyone know how/why these values are not in `/proc/sys/nfsd/portlist` in the first place and why I must do them manually ?  **And then what is the correct way to put those numbers there**, so that after boot my `/etc/fstab` nfs mounting of my data folder as rdma happens successfully?  The MLNX instructional pdf falls short.

I have been banging my head against the wall getting RDMA to work, there seems to be a lot of shortcoming with NFS overall, and I have a paid for cluster mgr software that has RDMA placeholders for configuration, but all mounts are always proto=tcp.  So if anyone can provide any information on anything described would be helpful, I will + any answer.

**Also:** I will end up doing `/etc/exports` with `secure` and choose some port number 1023 and below to satisfy security rules.  How do I choose a proper number in that range?  As ron nobody my understanding was I should never use port numbers below 1000 or 1024 for stuff I set up?

**update:** it appears that the `/etc/exports` parameter of *secure* or *insecure* is inconsequential.  What matters is having `rdma 20049` in `/proc/fs/nfsd/portlist` on the nfsserver.  With that, or any number, it appears to work with the *secure* exportfs.

Comment: can someone post or link the official below 1024 port number list?  internet assigned numbers authority (iana) ?  I am thinking of using port 249 for RDMA

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

Comment: I think so, although it would be nicer if it was presented as a single list I can scroll down vs 145 individual pages

Comment: does anyone know if ports <= 1023 are all spoken for?

Comment: there seems to be an oversight regarding NFS_RDMA as 20049 and not allowing for NFS "secure" being below port 1024.

Comment: if anyone has that IANA port number list in excel would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You have several questions and concerns regarding NFS (Network File System) version 4, its security options, port numbers, and the usage of RDMA (Remote Direct Memory Access).

NFS version 4, eliminated the need for multiple port numbers used in NFS version 3. Therefore, for NFSv4, all traffic is handled through TCP on port 2049.

[Security and NFS](https://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s06.html)

The `insecure` option in `/etc/exports` does not refer to the port number. It determines whether the NFS server will accept requests from any port on the client (insecure) or only from ports 1-1024 (secure). This option is unrelated to the well-known port 2049 used by NFSv4.

[What is insecure about the "insecure" option of NFS exports?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246527/what-is-insecure-about-the-insecure-option-of-nfs-exports)

The statement that the server will "*only operate on secure ports less than 1024*" is incorrect in the context of NFSv4, as it runs on port 2049, which is greater than 1024.

When using RDMA with NFS, you need to specify the `insecure` option in  `/etc/exports` to allow RDMA mounts. Without this option, NFS will default to using TCP `(proto=tcp)` instead of RDMA `(proto=rdma)`

For choosing a port number below 1024 select a port within the range 1-1023 that is not already assigned to a well-known service.

You can refer to the IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) service name and port number registry to ensure you don't select a port already in use.

[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)

Check your `/etc/services` contains the mapping of service names to port numbers:

`cat /etc/services`

> If you need a huge list of used numbers please install the nmap package.

Comment: I+'d your answer, however I still don't get your statement on how "insecure" option is incorrect in context of NFSv4 - you first say *does not refer to the port number* but then say *It determines whether the NFS server will accept requests from any **port***.

Comment: @ron TCP connections use a port on the client and a separate port on the server. The "insecure"/"secure" option refers to the client-side port (i.e. whether or not to limit that to ports less than 1024, which require privileges on the client (at least on Linux)), not the server-side port which is 2049.

Comment: As a bit of historical context: in early unix networks, individual users did not have administrative access to the network, but usually could bind to ports >=1024. That means that in such networks, connections from ports <1024 were guaranteed to come from non-user controlled system daemons. Nowadays, secure vs. insecure makes very little difference.

Answer (score 2):

regarding `/proc/fs/nfsd/portlist` which is largely the problem

https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-nfs/patch/20190830092058.18021-1-yongcheng.yang@gmail.com/

the `/etc/nfs.conf` file in RHEL 8 interpreted as a *template*  has `#rdma=n` in it.  So one would logically think just uncomment and do `rdma=y`.... where `y` equals yes.  This doesn't work completely.

You have to do `rdma=nfsrdma` instead of `rdma=y`.  Then `rdma 20049` will show up in `/proc/fs/nfsd/portlist`.  Or I assume whatever `rdma-port` is specified as in `/etc/nfs.conf`.  Then NFS RDMA works; this is with MLNX installed.  It takes a minute after doing `service nfs-server restart` to observe the change in proc.

Comment: I have also observed `rdma 20049` does not happen in `/proc/fs/nfsd/portlist` after boot.  **I have to manally do** a `service nfs-server restart` and then it will be there.  Seems like nfsv4beta.